# How to Join two different tables in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, join, eloquent

> QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'site_name' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select `email_date`, `url`, `recipient` from
>   `report_list` where `site_name` = mywebsite)

```
$records = DB::table('report_list')
              ->select('email_date','url','recipient') 
              ->where('site_name',$site_name)
              ->get();
return records;

return view('monthlyReport')
           ->with('records',$records)
           ->with('site_name',$site_name);
```

My `site_name` was on different table and I don't know if I need to put Join or Make a model for this two.

Can someone help me with this query?

Answer (score 2):

If you show the tables to see the columns and table names could help you better, while these are some examples:

```
//Option 1            
$results = DB::table('users')
->join('business', 'users.id', '=', 'business.user_id')
->select('users.*', 'business.name', 'business.telephone', 'business.address')
->get();

//Option 2
$results = User::join("business as b","users.id","=","business.user_id")
->select(DB::raw("users.*"), "b.name as business_name", "b.telephone as business_telephone", "b.address as business_address")                        
->get();
```

The laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all You need to add column named "site_name" to your "report_list" table in database.
2. this query is for you to join 2 tables (here I took example "users" table as second table If your second table is defferent use your) ->

   ```
   $records = DB::table('report_list')
                       ->join('users', 'report_list.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                       ->where('report_list.site_name', '=', $site_name);
                       ->select('users.*', 'report_list.email_date','report_list.url','report_list.recipient')
                       ->get();
       return view('monthlyReport')
              ->with(['records' => $records , 'site_name' => $site_name ]);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model for your other table which I assume it's `Site` then in the `report_list` model create a relation method like :

```
public function sites(){
   return $this->hasOne(Site::class);
}
```

or:

```
public function sites(){
   return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Site);
}
```

After that in your eloquent query use this :

```
$records = DB::table('report_list')
              ->select('email_date','url','recipient') 
              ->whereHas('sites', function($query){
                        $query->where('site_name',$site_name);
               })
              ->with('sites')
              ->get();
```